# how to get string value between underscores in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have string called `"RAM_ESH_BABU_SAR"`.

My requirement is to get the value from first character to second underscore i.e `RAM_ESH` and and also get the value after last underscore of from a input string i.e `SAR`.

Please suggest me query. Below code i have tried.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'RAM_ESH_BABU_SAR', '[^_]+', 1, 2 )
FROM
    dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with the position of the second and third underscore in the source string so I suggest using REGEXP_INSTR() within SUBSTR(). For the string after the third underscore you also need LENGTH() as you want to work backwards from the end character (i.e. a negative number of chars as the second paratmeter in SUBSTR().

> ```
> SELECT
>       substr(x,1,REGEXP_INSTR( x, '[_]+', 1, 2 )-1)         as part1
>     , substr(x,REGEXP_INSTR( x, '[_]+', 1, 3 ) - LENGTH(x)) as part2
> FROM
>     (select 'RAM_ESH_BABU_SAR' x from dual)
> ```
>
> ```
> PART1   | PART2
> :------ | :----
> RAM_ESH | SAR
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b3debe14dc5cc6cbe6deaa45f21f6f0b)*